# How to pass checkbox input into a function in shinyServer()

Tags: javascript, r, checkbox, shiny

I have this [Shiny](http://shiny.rstudio.com/) code, which is currently deployable via [RStudio](https://www.rstudio.com/products/RStudio/). 
I expect it to take the user input from Checkbox and pass the value
to `get_table()` parameter `logit`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggrepel)
library(shiny)
library(DT)
#-------------------------
# Function 
#-------------------------
get_table <- function (dat, logit=FALSE, wanted_cols = c("model","mpg","wt"), data_title="Foo table") {

  # This function creates a table 
  # an perform log function if logit=TRUE

  dat_out <- select(dat, one_of(wanted_cols)) 
  if(logit) {
    dat_out <- select(dat, one_of(wanted_cols[2:length(wanted_cols)])) 
    dat_out <- log(dat_out)
    dat_out <- bind_cols(dat[1], dat_out)

  }
  return(dat_out)

}

#-------------------------
# Begin Shiny App code (ui + server)
#-------------------------
# I literally want to use file as input 
infile <- "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/seankross/a412dfbd88b3db70b74b/raw/5f23f993cd87c283ce766e7ac6b329ee7cc2e1d1/mtcars.csv"
dat <- read_delim(infile,delim=",", col_types = cols())  
get_table(dat,logit=TRUE, wanted_cols=c("model","mpg","wt"), data_title="Cool Table")

ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(

    #  Application title
    titlePanel("Checkbox"),

    # Sidebar with sliders that demonstrate various available
    # options
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        checkboxInput("checkbox", label = "Log Scale", value = FALSE)        
      ),

      # Show a table summarizing the values entered
      mainPanel(
        DT::dataTableOutput('myplot_table')
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  output$value <- renderPrint({ input$checkbox })
  out_table <- get_table(dat,logit=FALSE, wanted_cols=c("model","mpg","wt"), data_title="Cool Table")
  output$myplot_table <- DT::renderDataTable(
    DT::datatable(out_table, options = list(pageLength = 10))
  )
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Currently the Apps looks like this:

[image]

Now, when I checked the box, it doesn't pass the parameter to `logit` function.
If it works the value it the table will be log.

My question is how can I pass the checkbox value to the parameter in `shinyServer()` ? I tried this

```
out_table <- get_table(dat,logit=input$checkbox, wanted_cols=c("model","mpg","wt"), data_title="Cool Table")
```

but gave error:

```
Warning: Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext: Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)
Stack trace (innermost first):
    47: .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext
    46: .subset2(x, "impl")$get
    45: $.reactivevalues
    44: $ [/Users/pduboois/Desktop/Test/toy_app/etc/allinone_app.R#11]
    43: get_table [/Users/pduboois/Desktop/Test/toy_app/etc/allinone_app.R#11]
    42: server [/Users/pdubooisa/Desktop/Test/toy_app/etc/allinone_app.R#57]
     1: runApp
Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() : 
  Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You store something in an output (`output$value <- renderPrint(...)`) but you never actually put that output in your UI. If you change your main panel to:

```
mainPanel(
        DT::dataTableOutput('myplot_table'),
        verbatimTextOutput('value')
      )
```

at least you see the value appearing. This one is `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

Your second mistake is to forget that your `out_table` should be reactive. Otherwise it's only calculated once, being at the time of initialization of the app.

So change the assignment in your server to:

```
out_table <- reactive({
    get_table(dat,logit=input$checkbox, 
              wanted_cols=c("model","mpg","wt"), 
              data_title="Cool Table")})
output$myplot_table <- DT::renderDataTable(
    DT::datatable(out_table(), options = list(pageLength = 10))
  )
```

pay attention: you get the value of a reactive value by calling it as a function (i.e. `out_table()` in the call to `datatable`)

Comment: Thanks. How can we know when to use `reactive()` or not in `shinyServer()` ? Any rule of thumb?

Comment: @neversaint you use reactive() if you have output that should change when the value of your reactive value changes. You find more explanation on what reactivity actually is on following page : http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/reactivity-overview.html

Comment: Is there a case when `checkboxInput()` is not reactive?

Comment: @neversaint The input is reactive, but `out_table` is not in your code. So that one is NOT updated when `input$checkbox` gets updated. And hence the table (which only depends on `out_table`) isn't either. That's where you went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there! Simply make it reactive so that it will change according to its reactive values (the checkbox):

```
out_table <- reactive({
    return(get_table(dat,logit=input$checkbox, wanted_cols=c("model","mpg","wt"), data_title="Cool Table"))
})
```

and use `out_table()` instead of `out_table` in `output$myplot_table`.